# How do you add a WordPress admin page without adding it to the menu?

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a WordPress plugin and I'd like to have an edit-item page that can't be reached via the submenu (because then the item wouldn't be specified).

This resource (http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus) shows how to associate an admin page with a function, but not how to do so without adding it as a menu item.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this can be done (well, technically, it would be more like registering the whole thing and then removing the menu item later), but It would just be easiest (I think) to check for parameters in the `$_GET` super-global to indicate that the user wishes to edit a specific item.

For example, you could have a page that lists items to edit, and clicking 'edit' only adds the item's ID to the current URL(query-string).

In the function that displays this page, if ID is defined, give them the page to edit that item.

Otherwise, give them the list view. That's how posts, pages, and other custom post types do it.

Answer (score 84):

Best solution here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-backend-page-without-menu-item

> use `add_submenu_page` with parent slug = null

Comment: One problem with this solution is that it becomes impossible to highlight a parent menu item when viewing this admin page. This is because `get_admin_page_parent()` always overrides the `$parent_file` global with the original parent, which is `null`. This happens after the `parent_file` filters are applied.

Comment: Another problem is that `get_admin_page_title()` returns empty string if we set parent slug to null. I suggest setting it to whatever we know we won't use in the future, like some hash. This is not perfect as the concept, but it does what we want - no item is being added to menu and we are still able to use `get_admin_page_title()`.

Comment: @ragulka used javascript to remove class wp-has-current-submenu from all #adminmenu children li, and add it to li of the parent.

Comment: @ragulka I've found a way to do it without JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47577455/1924128

Comment: In WordPress 4.9, I had to set the parent slug to an empty string.

Comment: @WesamAlalem Accepted solution is the best one. Just add a parameter called action to the URL and render the template based on that action.

Answer (score 27):

I have finally discovered a way to do this that isn't an ugly hack, doesn't require JS to highlight the desired menu item (and submenu item), and works for regular menus registered by plugins ([@Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36026345/1924128) only works for custom post types).

Essentially, you just need to register your submenu normally, but then hook into the `'submenu_file'` filter to deregister it and optionally also set another submenu item to highlight instead.

```
function so3902760_wp_admin_menu() {

    // Register the parent menu.
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Parent title', 'textdomain' )
        , __( 'Parent', 'textdomain' )
        , 'manage_options'
        , 'my_parent_slug'
        , 'display_my_menu'
    );

    // Register the hidden submenu.
    add_submenu_page(
        'my_parent_slug' // Use the parent slug as usual.
        , __( 'Page title', 'textdomain' )
        , ''
        , 'manage_options'
        , 'my_hidden_submenu'
        , 'display_my_submenu'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'so3902760_wp_admin_menu' );

function so3902760_wp_admin_submenu_filter( $submenu_file ) {

    global $plugin_page;

    $hidden_submenus = array(
        'my_hidden_submenu' => true,
    );

    // Select another submenu item to highlight (optional).
    if ( $plugin_page && isset( $hidden_submenus[ $plugin_page ] ) ) {
        $submenu_file = 'submenu_to_highlight';
    }

    // Hide the submenu.
    foreach ( $hidden_submenus as $submenu => $unused ) {
        remove_submenu_page( 'my_parent_slug', $submenu );
    }

    return $submenu_file;
}
add_filter( 'submenu_file', 'so3902760_wp_admin_submenu_filter' );
```

Comment: This is the only thing that achieved the result i was after thanks!
I stripped the `submenu_file` filter right back so it was only doing `remove_submenu_page( 'x_slug', 'y_slug' );return $submenu_file;`

Comment: This is perfect. It is also the solution to avoid an issue with PHP 8.2+ Thanks for sharing this tip.

Answer (score 11):

add_submenu_page with parent slug = null

OR

add_submenu_page with menu title = null

Comment: Verified your method. Works fine: add_submenu_page(NULL,'Page Title','Page Title','add_user','slug/to/new/page');

Comment: If just `menu_title` is `null` it will have no text but you can still click on it due to padding.

Answer (score 6):

> Note: This solution doesn't automatically set the current menu and submenu item. If you want to highlight a particular menu as current when the hidden page is viewed, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47577455/1924128).

From the answers that come before me, you can see that there are many ways to do this. However, there is another way that I think may be the best.

Loading the page differently based on the value of a `$_GET` query var is one option, but it may not be what some people are looking for.

The suggestions regarding `add_submenu_page()` are on the right track, but each of the previous suggestions have problems. Setting `$menu_title` to `null` doesn't keep the menu item from being displayed, it just makes it so the link doesn't have any text. The link still takes up some room in the menu though, so it looks funny. Setting the `$parent_slug` to `null` doesn't have this problem, but I noticed that the page's HTML `title` doesn't display the `$page_title` text.

My solution was to set `$parent_slug` to a fake menu slug, like `'i_dont_exist'`. The menu item won't be displayed, and when viewing the admin screen the page title will be filled out properly.

```
add_submenu_page(
    '_doesnt_exist'
    ,__( 'Page title', 'textdomain' )
    ,''
    ,'manage_options'
    ,'menu_slug'
    ,'display_my_menu'
);
```

Comment: Works! The URL to the new page in the example above is: `admin_url( 'options.php?page=menu_slug' )`

Comment: You just have to make `'_doesnt_exist'` an empty value so WordPress won't tell in which menu to append the link.. Thanks!!

Comment: 4.9 WP - get "you do not have permissions to view" error :S

Answer (score 6):

use this code for creating new page without adding in menu

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_newpage' );

function register_newpage(){
    add_menu_page($appname, $appname, 'administrator','custompage', 'custom');
    remove_menu_page('custom');
}

function custom()
{
echo "hai";
}
```

Comment: should be remove_menu_page('custompage');

Comment: Funnily enough, this works - the page remains registered, but the menu item is removed. Though the issue is that the page title is also removed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is very possible to make a page cannot be reach via submenu, or even the main menu in the WP admin panel. See the code snippet below.

```
function myplugin_render_edit_page() {
    // Code contains the UI for edit page.
}

/**
 * Manage menu items and pages.
 */
function myplugin_register_admin_page() {
    global $_registered_pages;

    $menu_slug = plugin_basename('myplugin.php');
    $hookname = get_plugin_page_hookname($menu_slug,'');
    if (!empty($hookname)) {
        add_action($hookname, 'myplugin_render_edit_page');
    }
    $_registered_pages[$hookname] = true;
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin_register_admin_page');
```

Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: how would you link to this from another admin page?

Comment: helpful, but you probably should not be directly editing $_registered_pages, it's not future-proof

Answer (score 4):

Create sub menu page and parent slug leave it empty like this:

```
// Create page were you can add new users.
    public function add_create_user_menu() {
        add_submenu_page(
            '',
            'Create User',
            'Create User',
            'manage_options',
            'create-user',
            array( $this, 'add_create_user_page' )
        );
    }
```

You can access it like this:

```
<a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=create-user">Add New</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all of the suggestions here but with various issues associated with each.

[The WordPress codex for add_submenu_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) now gives the correct answer, which is to use options.php as your parent slug. I tried the trick of using a made up name but that gives permissions errors, equally use of null at various locations either causes the menu text to simply be missing (but still clickable) or for the browser title to go missing.

Using options.php worked and I've not seen any issues as a result of its use.

Comment: Still unable to highlight parent menu item when viewing this page.

Answer (score 1):

Using add_submenu_page with a parent of NULL definitely works, however if you want to keep the non-linked page associated with a particular menu (say a custom post type menu), you have to use a variation of @Boopathi's answer:

```
function my_hidden_submenu_page(){
    //add the submenu page the usual way
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=custom-type', 'My Page Title', 'My Page Title', 'manage_options', 'my-page-slug', 'my_page_callback');
    //then remove it
    remove_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=custom-type','my-page-slug');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_hidden_submenu_page');
```

It looks as though the two actions would cancel each other out, however [remove_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page) does not unregister the callback function; it merely removes the link.

This way when someone is viewing your non-linked page, the correct navigation menu (our custom post type menu in this example) will still show as active.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I found with merely adding null as the parent slug for a sub menu item is that if you're currently viewing that specific page the submenu itself won't display (at least it didn't for me (along with the page title not showing).

What I did was add an empty span element inside the menu title and use jquery to traverse the parent elements and hide it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this need is still valid for nowadays version.
I am using `WordPress 5.3.2` and I used the following methods to remove the parent named menu from the `submenu`.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'submenus' ); 

function submenus()
    {
        global $submenu;

        $parent_slug = 'parent_slug_name';

        // remove parent named menu from submenu because it is always the first one in the submenu array, so the offset is 0 and remove just 1
        array_splice( $submenu[$parent_slug], 0, 1 ); // with reindex
        // or unset( $submenu[$parent_slug][0] ); // without reindex
    }
```

Hope it helps others who want to achieve the same goal.

- About php [array_splice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)
- this method could be found in the source of WP function [remove_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/) which is available since WP 3.1.0

#### Edit / Added

Apart from submenu, parent menu could also be updated in similar way.
For parent menu, the global variable is `$menu`.
example for reference:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'modify_menu_title' ) );

function modify_menu_title() {
    global $menu;

    $page = 'some-page-slug';
    $new_menu_title = 'New Title Name';
    foreach( $menu as $key => $value ) {
        if( $menu[$key][2] === $page ) {
            $menu[$key][0] = $new_menu_title;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I find you can do it by reusing the insert id, like so:

```
add_menu_page( 'User AS Packages', 'User AS', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/editaspackages.php', 'UserASPackages', '', 8);
add_menu_page( 'User ARP Packages', 'User ARP', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/editarppackages.php', 'UserARPPackages', '', 8);
add_menu_page( 'AS Packages', 'AS Packages', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/ars-s2.php', 'ARPPackages', '', 8);
```

The last 3 using position 8 and the last one overrides the two before so the two before do not appear.