# Custom page in Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am creating simple plugin, and I prepared few pages: add.php, edit.php, delete.php and list.php. I've used add_menu_page and add_submenu_page - so I understand why they are visible in admin menu. How to create page (or custom URL with parameter) without putting this into menu? I'd like to add link to edit page and delete url (code executed by plugin) on listing page - something like in posts listing page but can't find function to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions for this questions:

[How do you add a WordPress admin page without adding it to the menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902760/how-do-you-add-a-wordpress-admin-page-without-adding-it-to-the-menu)

Personally i havent tried it but it like the one where you remove the item from the menu after you set things up like normal.

There is also a great plugin called the **WP Router** that can help you setup totally unique urls with the callback you desire.

Comment: I found the solution. I used add_submenu_page() and as parent_slug I put null, so pages are created but aren't visible in admin menu.