# How to show edit form in custom wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show an edit form to wordpress admin in custom plugin when he clicked on edit link. But i don't know how to show the page that contain the edit form and how to pass the id of the row that i want to update it.
All user shows in the table, and i add an edit link for all of them, The code that i have is:
(all-user.php in include directory)

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>         
<tr>    
    <td>        
        <a href="updateUser.php?id=<?= $user->id ?>">edit it</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And i have an edit-user.php in include directory for show the form to wordpress admin:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>edit the user</h1>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">                
        <input name="name" value="<?= $_GET['id']; ?>"> 
        <input type="submit" name="editUser" value="update it">     
    </form>
</div>
```

I define a Database class to work with database, and define some methode such as selectAll, insert, delete, update.

---

I created three folder for custom plugin (css, images and includes)

---

Detabase.php and index.php is in the root of my custom plugin.

Comment: Ahad, your question is little unclear.where to want to show edit form page. If you have a list of user and want to redirect them to edit page.
Just assign your page in using add_submenu_page and use the menu slug in your edit link.

It will work

Comment: Thanks deepak-lakhara,
if i add submenu, when admin directly click on it what heppen (i mean there is no user id to edit when admin directly click on sub menu link), can i show the form in same 'list of user page'? When the edit link clicked only show the edit form and disappear list of user? or like laravel have a route only for show edit form?

Comment: Ahad,
Create a menu page and but don't show in menu using remove_menu_page function .
Using this your page is registered in plugin.
But you can use that and add you id using query parameter. So you will get id and work around that.

Comment: Thank you deepak-lakhara, Finaly i found the solution on this page: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902760/how-do-you-add-a-wordpress-admin-page-without-adding-it-to-the-menu/47577455#47577455)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a page to wordpress dashboard you can use `add_menu_page()` function. This function has 7 parameters. you can see hint to use this function in this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/). this function has a parameter for callback function you can add your form. For handle form submit you can see an example in this [link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/).